# How I keep intact my first two columns while I am searching a key word in 3rd column?

Tags: python, regex

I am new and working on Big Data use case.

I have huge amount of text extract and this extract is in `.txt` file & has 3 columns.

Each column is separated by ‘space’. 1st and 2nd columns are customer number and customer place; 3rd column is customer feedback. This ‘Customer feedback’ has free text (one line 50+ lines).

I have two objectives.

1. Replace the ‘spaces’ with pipe
2. Search the specific key words in 3rd column (customer feedback) and grab the 2 words front and two words back to key word.

At the end I have to create a new file with same 3 columns but limited text (or number of records which matches the search criteria).

My file and code:

---

```
s = """ABC000012088 MONA    Nice guy, would like to talk to him - he is not so nice in my view


ABCRERERWEADF8702000012088  BONA    VERY rude but looks nice, time is 15:40

12088   CITA    {Hello very nice but very hard to convence"""

#str = s.read()

print (s.replace("  ", "|"))

findword = 'nice'
numwords = 2

for i in s.split('\n'):
    z = i.split(' ')

    for x in [x for (x, y) in enumerate(z) if findword in y]:
        print(' '.join(z[max(x-numwords,0):x+numwords+1]))
```

---

With above code, I was able to replace ‘spaces’ with pipe and search key words as well. But my output is fragmented or separate. But my desired output is like below. 
So that,

- I have to combine output to below format &
- Have to export that data to new file.

Can someone help me please?

### Desired output in new file is this below format:

```
ABC000012088|MONA|not so nice in my
ABCRERERWEADF8702000012088|BONA|but looks nice, time is
12088|CITA|{Hello very nice but very
```

---

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `.splitlines` to split string into lines
2. Weed out empty lines
3. For each line, `.split(None, 2)` to split 2 times at white space - the freeform comments stay in the 3rd field
4. Put keyword finding in a function for clarity.
5. Join with `'|'` as separator.

Thus

```
keywords = { 'nice', 'funny', 'not' }
def get_keywords(text):
    return ' '.join(w for w in text.lower().split() if w in keywords)

for line in s.splitlines():  # 1
    if not line.strip():
        continue  # 2
    fields = line.split(None, 2)  # 3
    fields[2] = get_keywords(fields[2])  # 4
    joined = '|'.join(fields)  # 5
    print(joined)
```

Outputs:

```
ABC000012088|MONA|nice not nice
ABCRERERWEADF8702000012088|BONA|
12088|CITA|nice
```

---

As a bonus, if you are reading from a file, or `sys.stdin`, you can directly do:

```
for line in file:
    ...
```

or

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

Comment: @ Antti Haapala   Looks great. But only one thing is missing here. I would like to grab 2 words before and after key word. And also I noticed that if there is a “,” after keyword, program is not picking. 
The below code is working for picking 2 words before and after key word. Is it possible to incorporate the same?
-----------------------------------
findword = 'nice'
numwords = 2

for i in s.split('\n'):
    z = i.split(' ')

    for x in [x for (x, y) in enumerate(z) if findword in y]:
        print(' '.join(z[max(x-numwords,0):x+numwords+1]))

-------------------